# Using Entity Framework or GridView to pivot data in C# ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I essentially have this dataset:

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
GridView gridView = new GridView();
gridView.DataSource = db.Services;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Which gives me this table:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
|   Name    |  Machine  | Status  | Version |
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
| Service 1 | Machine 1 | Running |   2.2.2 |
| Service 1 | Machine 2 | Running |   2.2.2 |
| Service 1 | Machine 3 | Running |   2.2.2 |
| Service 2 | Machine 1 | Running |   2.2.2 |
| Service 2 | Machine 2 | Running |   2.2.2 |
| Service 2 | Machine 3 | Running |   2.2.2 |
| Service 3 | Machine 1 | Running |   2.2.2 |
| Service 3 | Machine 2 | Running |   2.2.2 |
| Service 3 | Machine 3 | Running |   2.2.2 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

I would now like to "pivot" the name column to get a table like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  Machine  | Service 1 | Service 2 | Service 3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Machine 1 | Running   | Running   | Running   |
| Machine 2 | Running   | Running   | Running   |
| Machine 3 | Running   | Running   | Running   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am simply wondering if Entity Framework or GridView have any good tools to do this. I have been trying to find a solution on google, but short of creating my own pivot function I haven't found any useful solutions.

**Edit 2:**

**Notice:** This is a slimmed down version of my actual environment. I have more than 3 machines to monitor and the ability to dynamically add more machines. I do only have 3 services at the moment, but this will probably expand later with `Service 4` and `Service 5` on existing or new machines. So I need a general solution for the pivoting. Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

I have tried to use Entity Framework to create a view by using PIVOT:

```cs
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
"CREATE VIEW pivotedServices AS (" +
"SELECT " +
    "Machine, [Service 1], [Service 2], [Service 3] " +
"FROM " +
    "(dbo.Services) " +
"PIVOT" +
"( Status FOR [Name] IN ( [Service 1], [Service 2], [Service 3])) AS pvt);"
);
```

But didn't get it to work. Kept getting error "near '('.", after some testing it seems to be the first parenthesis before the `SELECT` statement that is the issue. Removing the surrounding parenthesis gives error "near SELECT.". Thus, I gave up on this idea.

I also have tried using a couple of for-loops to "pivot" manually, I got it working fairly well. But I feel like there should be a better solution. If there isn't, fine I guess, but I'm hoping you guys have one.

Comment: you should design a sql query for this problem and show what you tried in `Gridview`.

Comment: Haven't tried anything "in GridView", since I haven't found any useful tools for it. What I have tried is manually looping through my data with a couple of for-loops before binding it. But I feel like there must be a "better way" out there. I haven't found it yet though.

Comment: I added a database queries below of your problem.

Comment: @Asif.Ali Great answer, see my comment and edit please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

First, Normalize your table into three Tables ('Services','Machines','Service_Machine'):

```
CREATE TABLE Services 
(
    ServiceId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    Name VARCHAR (25), 
    Status VARCHAR (25), 
    Version VARCHAR (25)
);

CREATE TABLE Machines 
(
    MachineId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    Name VARCHAR (25)
);

// this table is created as above two tables have Many-to-Many Relationship

CREATE TABLE Service_Machine 
(
    ServiceId INTEGER REFERENCES Services (ServiceId), 
    MachineId INTEGER REFERENCES Machines (MachineId)
);
```

And then create two Views ('SimpleView', 'PivotView'):

```
CREATE VIEW SimpleView AS 
SELECT s.ServiceId, s.Name AS 'Name',m.MachineId, m.Name AS 'Machine',s.Status,s.Version 
FROM Services AS s,Machines AS m,Service_Machine AS sm 
WHERE s.ServiceId=sm.ServiceId 
AND m.MachineId=sm.MachineId
```

`SimpleView` output which you can bind with gridview:

[image]

**Extended:**

Create one more view `ViewStatus`:

```
select distinct(sv.ServiceId) as 'ServiceId', sv.Name, sv.Status 
from SimpleView sv 
inner join SimpleView sv2 on sv.MachineId = sv2.MachineId 
inner join SimpleView sv3 on sv.ServiceId = sv2.ServiceId
```

And Now you have to create `PivotView` view in **.CS Code**:

```
private void CreatePivotView()
    {
        MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
        DataTable dt = db.ViewStatus; // get data from ViewStatus that is in your database
        int count = 1;
        String query = "CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS PivotView AS SELECT DISTINCT(Machine) AS 'Machine', ";

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            query += "(SELECT status FROM StatusView WHERE ServiceId=" + dr["ServiceId"] + ") AS 'Service " + dr["ServiceId"] + "'";
            if (dt.Rows.Count != count)
            {
                query += ";";
            }
            else
            {
                query += " ";
            }
            count++;
        }

        query += "from SimpleView";

        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
    }
```

`PivotView` output which you can bind with gridview:
[image]

**Note:** SQLITE Studio is used for designing above database queries.

Comment: Very clear and thorough answer, thank you! However, and this is on me for not stating so in the question, I have more than 3 machines and also have the capability to dynamically add machines. At the moment I only monitor 3 services, but that might expand. There might be `Service 4` and `Service 5` on the same or other machines in the future. So basically, I would need the creation of `PivotView` to be more general, at least for the machines as it is right now, but preferably for the services too. If you manage that, this will be the perfect answer to my actual (but hidden) question. Will edit.

Comment: @Skillzore I edited my answer. Now it will create services columns dynamically as you want. See **Extended Part**

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! :)